# Dynamic array variable is not showing in Local Variables debug window

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-xe

I've got something that I've never saw before. A local variable that doesn't appear in Local Variables windows when debugging. I'm attaching a image.[image: WHY U NO SHOWN THERE?]

As you can see, I'm using the variable in code and optimization is disabled when debugging. But I'm also using generics and anonymous methods, things that I'm not a specialist.
 The code of the problematic procedure is this (What the procedure does is order the two first arrays ArrayNomes, ArrayValores by length of the string in first array in a desc order):

```
  procedure OrdenarArrays(var ArrayNomes, ArrayValores: array of string; var ArrayIndices: array of Integer);
  var
    Comparer: IComparer<Integer>;
    I: Integer;
    tmpNomesCampos, tmpValoresCampos: array of String;
  begin

    SetLength(tmpNomesCampos,   cdsCadastro.FieldCount);
    SetLength(tmpValoresCampos, cdsCadastro.FieldCount);

    //Carregar os NomesCampos para serem usados na comparação
    for I := 0 to High(arrayIndices) do
    begin
      tmpNomesCampos[I] := ArrayNomes[I];
    end;

    { Cria novo delegatedcomparer. Ele permite o uso de um callback para comparar os arrays}
    Comparer := TDelegatedComparer<Integer>.Create(
      { TComparison<Integer> }
      function(const Left, Right: Integer): Integer
      begin
        {colocar em ordem decrescente de acordo com o tamanho do nome do campo}
//        Result := Left - Right;
        Result := -(Length(tmpNomesCampos[Left]) - Length(tmpNomesCampos[Right]));
      end);

    { Ordena o Array base }
    TArray.Sort<Integer>(arrayIndices, Comparer);

    //Reordenar os NomesCampos de acordo com o array IndicesCampos
    for I := 0 to High(arrayIndices) do
    begin
      tmpNomesCampos[I]   := ArrayNomes[arrayIndices[I]];
      tmpValoresCampos[I] := ArrayValores[arrayIndices[I]];
    end;

    //Salvar nos arrays definitivos;
    for I := 0 to High(arrayIndices) do
    begin
      ArrayNomes[I]   := tmpNomesCampos[I];
      ArrayValores[I] := tmpValoresCampos[I];
    end;

  end;
```

Is this variable not showing a bug? Is it an already known bug? Or could it be a feature on using generics and anonymous methods that I don't know?

System: Windows 7 64 bits/Delphi XE (latest updates)

---

UPDATE: Changed the code to a simplified console version below. This may help anyone who want to test in his Delphi version.
Note: It doesn't fill the original arrays, because it is not necessary to show the issue;

```
program Project1;


{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Generics.Collections, Generics.Defaults;

  procedure OrdenarArrays(var ArrayNomes, ArrayValores: array of string; var ArrayIndices: array of Integer);
  var
    Comparer: IComparer<Integer>;
    I: Integer;
    tmpNomesCampos, tmpValoresCampos: array of String;
  begin

    SetLength(tmpNomesCampos,   Length(arrayIndices));
    SetLength(tmpValoresCampos, Length(arrayIndices));

    //Carregar os NomesCampos para serem usados na comparação
    for I := 0 to High(arrayIndices) do
    begin
      tmpNomesCampos[I] := ArrayNomes[I];
    end;

    { Cria novo delegatedcomparer. Ele permite o uso de um callback para comparar os arrays}
    Comparer := TDelegatedComparer<Integer>.Create(
      { TComparison<Integer> }
      function(const Left, Right: Integer): Integer
      begin
        {colocar em ordem decrescente de acordo com o tamanho do nome do campo}
  //        Result := Left - Right;
        Result := -(Length(tmpNomesCampos[Left]) - Length(tmpNomesCampos[Right]));
      end);

    { Ordena o Array base }
    TArray.Sort<Integer>(arrayIndices, Comparer);

    //Reordenar os NomesCampos de acordo com o array IndicesCampos
    for I := 0 to High(arrayIndices) do
    begin
      tmpNomesCampos[I]   := ArrayNomes[arrayIndices[I]];
      tmpValoresCampos[I] := ArrayValores[arrayIndices[I]];
    end;

    //Salvar nos arrays definitivos;
    for I := 0 to High(arrayIndices) do
    begin
      ArrayNomes[I]   := tmpNomesCampos[I];
      ArrayValores[I] := tmpValoresCampos[I];
    end;

  end;

var
  NomesCampos, ValoresCampos: array of String;
  IndicesCampos: array of Integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  try

    SetLength(NomesCampos,   42);
    SetLength(ValoresCampos, 42);
    SetLength(IndicesCampos, 42);

//    for I := 0 to 41 do

    OrdenarArrays(NomesCampos, ValoresCampos, IndicesCampos);

    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: First I would get rid of the dependency to cdsCadastro.FieldCount and pass it into the method. If that alone does not help you can move the method from being a local nested method.

Comment: can you make three lines, of which 1st and 3rd would use it, and then see if it is visible on the 2nd line. Or compile the program with optimizations disabled (recommended for debug). will it be shown on line #2, between array-using lines?

Comment: @Arioch'The Optimization is already disabled. My bad I will update the question.

Comment: Not much you can do. It seems to be a bug. Get a later Delphi. You are four versions out of date.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you mean let him exchange known bugs to unknown ? :-)

Comment: But please make the test with those three lines

Comment: @Arioch'The Did the test with those three lines, but that array is never shown.

Comment: @StefanGlienke I did not moved the method from nested because it is being used several times, but only there. Anyway, to test, I did followed your suggestion and exchanged it for `Length(arrayIndices)`. Unfortunately, it did not solved the issue. Also, if I add a watch to that variable, I receive the following error message: "E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'tmpNomesCampos'"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for your opinion. Maybe it is a bug. The last version we have is XE2. Unfortunately, I am not the person who pays for the license. I'm having trouble to convince the manager to buy new versions when 1) price is too high 2) six month upgrade policy 3) Only two version fixes policy... Anyway, can you confirm this is fixed in new version? Maybe is another argument I can use.

Comment: You should not upgrade to fix this bug. The bug is not important. You've spent more time chasing it than you would have done by just working around it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you confirm this is fixed in new version after XE2? Because I still see it in XE2.

Comment: Bug still present in XE5. I have a hunch what is the key factor. Just wait a minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a debugger/IDE bug that is still present in XE5. The problem is, as you suspected, related to the use of anonymous methods. The key is whether or not a variable is captured. When a variable is captured, that variable does not show up in the Locals window. Here is the shortest SSCCE that I can concoct:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

procedure Foo1;
var
  func: TFunc<Integer>;
  val: Integer;
begin
  val := 666;
  func :=
    function: Integer
    begin
      Result := val;
    end;
end;

procedure Foo2;
var
  func: TFunc<Integer>;
  val: Integer;
begin
  val := 666;
  func :=
    function: Integer
    begin
      Result := 666;
    end;
end;

begin
  Foo1;
  Foo2;
  Readln;
end.
```

In the debugger, `Foo1.val` does not show up in the Locals window. But `Foo2.val` does.

[QC#121821](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=121821)

Comment: Also, you cannot add a watch for `Foo1.val`

Comment: @LURD that involves more battling with QC and do they take any notice? I'm appalled they have not fixed the floating point control yet .....

Comment: It is still present in XE7 and XE8. Is there at least a workaround? The only thing I can think of is introducing additional local pointers to the variables and inspect them.

Comment: Note - issue still present in RAD Studio 11

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question but a suggestion on how to write the routine in a much simpler way (at least if I understood what it should do)

```
procedure OrderArrays(var ArrayNameValuePairs: array of TPair<string, string>);
begin
  TArray.Sort<TPair<string, string>>(ArrayNameValuePairs,
    TComparer<TPair<string, string>>.Construct(
      function(const Left, Right: TPair<string, string>): Integer
      begin
        Result := Length(Right.Key) - Length(Left.Key);
      end));
end;
```

As you can see I combined names and values as they obviously belong together. This makes sorting this combined array much easier as you do not have to sort a third array holding the indizes to reorder the two original arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this later. The advantage of using that third array is that I don't even really need to order the first two arrays and, even if I do, I can know what where the positions before the change.